# Crop Images before shown in LazyList

Tags: android, bitmap, crop, lazylist

I'm using the [LazyList](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList) to load images into a listview. But I would like just to show the Rect(8, 8, 16, 16) in the ListView. Is this possible using drawbitmap with the previous downloaded images? So download images to a temp directory, then cropping it and then showing in the ListView? How can I do this using Lazylist?

Answer (score 2):

You can just add some image processing into ImageLoader. It should be done after it is downloaded before it is displayed.